# Web browser showing as a line in device

Tags: java, codenameone

I tried to add the web-browser in code:

```
@Override
    protected void beforeMain(Form f) {

        final Container cont = new Container(new BorderLayout());
        String url = "https://www.google.com";

        WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser() {

            @Override
            public void onLoad(String url) {

                this.setShouldCalcPreferredSize(true);

                Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {

                        cont.revalidate();

                    }
                });
            }

        };

        web.setURL(url);
        cont.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, web);
        cont.revalidate();
        f.addComponent(cont);
}
```

In the simulator works fine but in Android device is showing one-pixel line...why?

thanks

Comment: You don't seem to be setting the dimensions.  Use the setWidth and setHeight methods with the MATCH_PARENT value so that it stretches.

Comment: I'm using codenameone...is it suppose to use setWidht or setHeight?

Comment: Both, so that the web view expands to fill the entire available area. You may need to do it to the container as well

Comment: MATCH_PARENT is not recognized in codenameone. I have tried  to setHeight but nothing happens is always one pixel line

Comment: I would recommend using codename one designer instead just adding web view in the container. That will be easy and quick too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because your form layout is a `FlowLayout`. Change your form Layout to `BorderLayout` and add the browser container to the `center`

```
@Override
protected void beforeMain(Form f) {

    final Container cont = new Container(new BorderLayout());
    String url = "https://www.google.com";

    WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser() {

        @Override
        public void onLoad(String url) {

            this.setShouldCalcPreferredSize(true);

            Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    cont.revalidate();

                }
            });
        }

    };

    web.setURL(url);
    cont.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, web);
    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    f.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, cont);
    f.revalidate();
}
```